# How to disable Content Testing in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: experience-editor, performance-optimization, content-testing

I tried to disable Optimization stuff for Experience editor and did everything that described here:

https://sitecoresaga.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/disabling-content-testing-in-sitecore-8-2/

and

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/785358

but I still see Optimization calls at Experience Editor

[image]

what I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution (For XP 8.1 And Later)

Change the ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled setting value to false in the App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.config file:

> `<setting name="ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled" value="false" />`

Comment: By "all the instructions", it's just a single setting for 8.1+ and the OP is on 8.2. Otherwise you've just linked back to the kb article the OP had posted...

Answer (score 0):

Content tests let you test alternative variants of your website's content to find out which pages, components, or combinations of components are the most effective with visitors. The content or components that you are comparing in a test should be designed to achieve the same goal.

Content testing is not working properly with CMS mode only. In other words, if you are disabling the analytical function (xDB).

First of all, let me list down the software versions that I used in this article

- Sitecore Experience Platform 8.1 rev. 160519 (8.1 Update-3)
- Solr4.10.4 - recommended Solr version for Sitecore 8.1

To disable content testing you should patch one of the Sitecore settings called ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled. You will need to set this value to false

[image]

Moreover, you can find few exceptions on crawling log files

> 4352 12:15:39 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField:
>   impact for indexable:
>   sitecore://master/{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}?lang=en&ver=1
>
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>
> Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Source: mscorlib
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type,
>   Object[] parameters)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>
> at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportingQueryBase..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase
>   reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
>
> at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Reporting.TimeRangeItemBasedReportingQuery..ctor(ID
>   queryItemId, ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider, CachingPolicy
>   cachingPolicy)
>
> at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Reporting.TestPotentialQuery..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase
>   reportProvider)
>
> at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestPotentialMetricBase.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable
>   indexable)
>
> at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexField(IComputedIndexField
>   computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState,
>   ConcurrentQueue`1 exceptions)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB
>
> at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.MongoDbReportDataSource..ctor(String
>   connectionStringName)

These exceptions are related to three computed fields that Sitecore is trying to index them. You can find these fields on the below files

- \App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config - If you are using Solr
- \App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config - if you are using Lucene

**Fields names are:**

- impact
- potential
- recommendation

In order to remove these exceptions you have to remove these lines form the above mentioned files, or follow the Sitecore best practices and create a separate config file under Include folder that will be responsible for removing these fields.

I've created these config files to make it easier for you :)

If you are using Solr, please use zz.Disable.Content.Testing.Solr.config
If you are using Lucene, please use zz.Disable.Content.Testing.Lucene.config

Downloads:

[zz.Disable.Content.Testing.Lucene.config](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HR-6SQQRU2mOVK8yvRh6CHeDymzzh5O0)

[zz.Disable.Content.Testing.Solr.config](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JlDwX7alZIgDnuMkK1Mh-fHG27IYzqAq)